# Which wiki software is integrated with SourceForge?

Tags: wiki, sourceforge

I'm on a team using SourceForge 4.3 Enterprise Edition and can't figure out what the wiki software is.  We thought it was Twiki for a while, but the features don't line up.  The help files mention "SourceForge Wiki," but Googling for that brings up a project that hasn't been active in over five years.  It also might not even be a proper noun.  So, does anyone know what wiki SourceForge uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I discovered that I'm actually using [CollabNet TeamForge](http://www.open.collab.net/products/ctf/seeit.html); I'm not clear on the relationship between that project and SourceForge yet, or why my team's site has a SourceForge logo.  The "Applications Integrated with..." page mentions [JSPWiki](http://www.jspwiki.org/).  JSPWiki's edit page looks like my project's edit page, so I'm considering this question answered.

Comment: In which case you could add final notes at the bottom of your question, and accept you answer (maybe even close your question).

Answer (score 2):

Going through the [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) main page to its [Site Support](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Support) link
leads to a [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) reference at the bottom.

SourceForge also shows up on the [TracUsers page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUsers).

Look at the specific area on SourceForge that you are interested in at their  [Hosted Apps page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Hosted%20Apps).

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I was looking for. It's my fault, I wasn't clear in the question.  I was wondering about a downloadable SourceForge, not sourceforge.net.  See my answer for more info.